# Seemingly straightforward: Integral of ratio of polynomials

Tags: integration

So, I have

$$
I=\int\frac{x (a-x)^{b}}{(c-\sqrt{d+g x+x^2})^{\frac{3}{2}(c-1)}}dx
$$

where $a,b,c,d$ and $g$ are all constants and the integrand is always real and positive.

Mathematica 10 and Wolfram Alpha fail, and I can't see any way of doing this without a binomial series, integrating term by term and then analytically evaluating the sum. Perhaps someone can help?

Apologies for not showing more working - I'm trying a technique where I differentiate $I$ with respect to one of the constants (then integrate by final answer back out), but to no avail so far....

### Edit (version 3)

Take $a=t$ (a positive integer), $b=\frac{3}{2}(t-1)$, $c=\lceil r_i \rceil + t$, $d=r_i^2$ ($r_i \in \mathbb{R}^+$) and $g=2 r_i \cos(\theta)$ where $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. Also, consider $\frac{x (a-x)^{b}}{c-\sqrt{d-g x+x^2}}$ to be $\in \mathbb{R}$ for all parameter values and for all $x$ (within the region of integration I consider, but do not explicitly state).

Note these parameters imply that $g^2-4d=4r_i^2(1-\cos^2\theta)$ (which is always positive).

Comment: There are way too many parameters involved (and the relation between $g^2$ and $4d$ is quite crucial in establishing the behaviour of the primitive), I doubt you will get any simple answer, even using special functions. Maybe it is worth to mention the original problem to address your work to something reachable.

Comment: OK hang, I'll add what the parameters and their relations are..

Comment: done, any ideas now?